# angular-datatables DTDefaultOptions not working

Tags: angularjs, datatables

I somehow can’t set defaults for the 15 tables in a app.
Even the API document looks simple, the tables have the default of 10 rows, instead of the 25 I am trying to set as default.

Did I miss something or need to change the order?

```
var app = angular.module("app", [
    'ui.router', 
    'datatables'
]);

app.run(function(DTDefaultOptions) {
    DTDefaultOptions.setDisplayLength(25);
});

app.controller('DataTablesCtrlArticles', function($scope, $http, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder) {
    ...
});
```

Comment: Can you update this [pen](http://codepen.io/l-lin/pen/bdYedr?editors=101) to reproduce your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Louis!

I was looking for a pen like this to play against and try to find the crucial different step by step.
Thanks to it, I was able to find out, what the issue causes.
In each controller I had a setting like this:

```
.withOption('lengthMenu', [
    [10, 25, 50, 100, -1],
    [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]
])
```

and somehow the global withDisplayLength is then overwritten with the first number, 10. This does not happen if withDisplayLength is set within the controllers.